# (Chrono Time) Minute tick detection error

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have an if statement in my code which is supposed to detect if my chrono::duration exceeds one minute of runtime. When the if statement becomes true it is supposed to print "Tick!" *only* once, but my program prints "Tick!" every time once the delta__time has exceeded a minute even if I subtract 60 seconds from it. You may have to look at the photo to get a better idea of the issue. I'm still working on explaining things well and this is only my second post on the site. How do I get my code to only print tick once per minute? Thanks lots.

```
int main()
{
    // Create Screen Buffer
    wchar_t* screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight];
    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    //SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

    wstring numberSystem[10] = {
    };

    while (1)
    {
        tp2 = chrono::system_clock::now();
        chrono::duration<long double, ratio<60>> delta__time = tp2 - tp1;

    if (delta__time >= 60s)
        {
            delta__time -= 60s;
            cout << "Tick!\t" << delta__time.count() << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << delta__time.count() << endl;
        }
        // Handle change in time here.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Chrono time minute tick detection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj0QP.png)

Answer (score -1):

As @drescherjm said, your problem is that the `-= 60s;` is discarded, as you recalculate delta time each iteration.

```
using namespace std::literals;

auto start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
long ticks = 0;
while (1)
{
  auto current_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::chrono::duration<long double, std::ratio<60>> delta_time = current_time - start_time;
  delta_time -= ticks * 60s; // note that `ticks` adds up.

  if (delta_time >= 60s)
  {
    ++ticks;
    std::cout << "Tick!\t" << delta_time.count() << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << delta_time.count() << std::endl;
  }
  // Handle change in time here.
}
```

I kept `start_time` as the unchanged start time, and `current_time` ditto, instead of doing something like adding to `tp1`.  It makes thinking about what those variables are really simple.

Comment: re last paragraph, reasonable, though just personally I prefer to modify the "start" conditions so that the algorithm (such as it is) is effectively invariant over time. You're just starting it "from scratch". Easier to test and to rationalise about, also one fewer variable to track mentally

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: And no (signed :/ ) overflows ... in a long time. ;-)

Comment: The simplest solutions are often the hardest to find. Thank you lots! I see where I went wrong. I probably could have caught it if the cout wasn't giving me what it was, and it is harder to visualize what is going on when you're dealing with scalars on a more conceptual level rather than understanding it visually like I've done with simpler programs. P.S. I'm with you both on modifying the start conditions instead of keeping track of ticks, and also you get the overflow protection. :)

Answer (score -1):

To close this post... I went ahead and added 60s to the tp1 variable for every minute tick that occurs. Thank you! :)

Here was the final code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

#include <Windows.h>

int nScreenWidth = 240;
int nScreenHeight = 80;

int nMapWidth = 8;
int nMapHeight = 5;

int main()
{
    // Create Screen Buffer
    wchar_t* screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight];
    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

    // Current Time
    int hourDoubleDigit = 1;
    int hourSingleDigit = 2;
    int minuteDoubleDigit = 0;
    int minuteSingleDigit = 0;

    // Character Mapping
    wstring numberSystem[10] = {
    };

    numberSystem[0] += L"########"; numberSystem[1] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[2] += L"########";
    numberSystem[0] += L"##   ###"; numberSystem[1] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[2] += L"      ##";
    numberSystem[0] += L"## ## ##"; numberSystem[1] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[2] += L"########";
    numberSystem[0] += L"###   ##"; numberSystem[1] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[2] += L"##      ";
    numberSystem[0] += L"########"; numberSystem[1] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[2] += L"########";

    numberSystem[3] += L"########"; numberSystem[4] += L"##    ##"; numberSystem[5] += L"########";
    numberSystem[3] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[4] += L"##    ##"; numberSystem[5] += L"##      ";
    numberSystem[3] += L"########"; numberSystem[4] += L"########"; numberSystem[5] += L"########";
    numberSystem[3] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[4] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[5] += L"      ##";
    numberSystem[3] += L"########"; numberSystem[4] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[5] += L"########";

    numberSystem[6] += L"########"; numberSystem[7] += L"########"; numberSystem[8] += L"########"; numberSystem[9] += L"########";
    numberSystem[6] += L"##      "; numberSystem[7] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[8] += L"##    ##"; numberSystem[9] += L"##    ##";
    numberSystem[6] += L"########"; numberSystem[7] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[8] += L"########"; numberSystem[9] += L"########";
    numberSystem[6] += L"##    ##"; numberSystem[7] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[8] += L"##    ##"; numberSystem[9] += L"      ##";
    numberSystem[6] += L"########"; numberSystem[7] += L"      ##"; numberSystem[8] += L"########"; numberSystem[9] += L"########";

    // Keeping Track of System Time
    auto tp1 = chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto tp2 = chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto TickInterval = 60s;

    while (1)
    {
        for (int xy = 0; xy <= nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight; xy++) screen[xy] = ' ';//To prevent buggy character spawning...
        // You don't always have to write this above line if you're already making use of writing characters to every space in the screen, but I'm not!


        // Let the program know a minute has passed... (Time passes too much too often)
        tp2 = chrono::system_clock::now();
        chrono::duration<long double> delta__time = tp2 - tp1;
        bool TICKhasOCCURED = false;

        if (delta__time >= TickInterval)
        {
            tp1 += TickInterval;
            TICKhasOCCURED = true;
        }

        if (TICKhasOCCURED)
        {
            if (minuteSingleDigit >= 9)
            {
                if (minuteDoubleDigit >= 5)
                {

                    if (hourSingleDigit >= 9 && hourDoubleDigit == 0)
                    {
                        hourDoubleDigit++;
                        hourSingleDigit = 0;
                        minuteDoubleDigit = 0;
                        minuteSingleDigit = 0;
                    }
                    else if (hourSingleDigit >= 2 && hourDoubleDigit == 1)
                    {
                        hourDoubleDigit = 0;
                        hourSingleDigit = 1;
                        minuteDoubleDigit = 0;
                        minuteSingleDigit = 0;

                    }
                    else {
                        hourSingleDigit++;
                        minuteDoubleDigit = 0;
                        minuteSingleDigit = 0;
                    }//After 59 minutes check the hour and change it.
                }
                else {
                    minuteDoubleDigit++;
                    minuteSingleDigit = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                minuteSingleDigit++;
            }
        }


        // The Current Time is then drawn out using the mapped characters.
        for(int ix = 0; ix < nMapWidth; ix++)
            for (int iy = 0; iy < nMapHeight; iy++)
            {
                screen[00 + ix + (nScreenWidth * iy)] = numberSystem[hourDoubleDigit][ix + (nMapWidth * iy)];
                screen[10 + ix + (nScreenWidth * iy)] = numberSystem[hourSingleDigit][ix + (nMapWidth * iy)];
                screen[20 + ix + (nScreenWidth * iy)] = numberSystem[minuteDoubleDigit][ix + (nMapWidth * iy)];
                screen[30 + ix + (nScreenWidth * iy)] = numberSystem[minuteSingleDigit][ix + (nMapWidth * iy)];
            }


        //Debug
        //cout << hourDoubleDigit << "\t" << hourSingleDigit << "\t" << minuteDoubleDigit << "\t" << minuteSingleDigit << endl;
        TICKhasOCCURED = false;

        screen[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight-1] = '\0';
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`delta__time` is recalculated at the start of every loop iteration, so changes to it won't have any lasting effect (though it does affect the `cout` immediately after it, which is why your values appear low).

You may wish to add 60s to `tp1` instead (or set it to `now()`, though this introduces errors).